# ! LaTeX Error: File `uarial.sty' not found

Tags: errors, installing

I am gettting the below error.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `uarial.sty' not found.
```

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [`uarial` README](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/)? It shows exactly what you need to do to install it.

Comment: I am installing on linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you have to install the "non free fonts" from CTAN which is easy with Linux.
run in a terminal:

```
wget -q https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
texlua ./install-getnonfreefonts
getnonfreefonts-sys -a
```

Depending on your system (Windows, latest Ubuntu,...), the last command should be

```
getnonfreefonts --sys -a
```

or if you have no root rights, then use

```
sudo texlua ./install-getnonfreefonts
sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a
```

Only for a local user based installation use `getnonfreefonts` instead of the `getnonfreefonts-sys`

That will install Arial and others in your local texmf/ directory. It is also possible under Windows with running `cmd` to get a terminal window, too.

Comment: bash: ./getnonfreefonts: No such file or directory

Comment: @gsamaras you may need to use sudo depending on your use and linux distribution.

Comment: The last command didn't work for me on Windows. Instead I had to use `getnonfreefonts --sys -a`

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem: `getnonfreefonts'  will already be changed so that `-sys` is no more needed, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by adding rights:

```
# sudo chmod u+x install-getnonfreefonts
```

than I ran

```
# sudo /home/dirk/install-getnonfreefonts -a
```

and

```
# sudo /usr/local/bin/getnonfreefonts -a
```

Comment: Is the doubled `sudo` in the third instruction a typo?

Comment: The `sudo` is not needed, as install-getnonfreefonts installs the fonts in `$TEXMFHOME`, i.e. your own dir. And of course the path `/home/dirk/` works only on your system.